# Apache Jena saving ttl file

Tags: java, rdf, jena

Hi I have created a model with Apache Jena and can output it this way:

```
model.write(System.out, "Turtle");
```

Is it possible to save the turtle file as .ttl on disk?

Answer (score 3):

To write your model to a file you just pass an `OutputStream` instead of `System.out`, like this:

```
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("output-model.ttl");
RDFDataMgr.write(out, model, Lang.TURTLE);
```

or:

```
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("output-model.ttl");
model.write(out, Lang.TURTLE);
```

Don't forget to close your stream once the file is fully written.

Comment: Java's try-with-resource will ensure the file is closed.
`try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("output-model.ttl") ) {
    model.write(out, Lang.TURTLE);
}
`

Comment: Yes, on a `finally` clause if you are on Java 6 or previous, or `@CleanUp` if you are using Lombok.